# Pass Django Model Object into Template Tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I created a custom template tag to query a list of objects, but each object has a tag associated with it.  I would like to pass an object as a filter into my template tag to display only certain tagged objects in my template.

**Template Tag**

```
@register.inclusion_tag(
    'tags/_documents_snippets.html',
    takes_context=True
)
def document_snippets(context):
    Document = get_document_model()
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return {
        'documents': documents,
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```

**Template**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="c-content-list-1 c-separator-dot c-square">
        {% for doc in documents %}
            <li><a href="{{ doc.url }}">{{ doc.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Tag**

```
{% document_snippets %}
```

Can I do something like `{% document_snippets|tags="AO Now" %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add arbitrary arguments to template tags like you can to regular functions. For example:

```
@register.inclusion_tag(
    'tags/_documents_snippets.html',
    takes_context=True
)
def document_snippets(context, **kwargs):
    Document = get_document_model()
    documents = Document.objects.filter(**kwargs)
    return {
        'documents': documents,
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```

And then call it with:

```
{% document_snippets tags="AO Now" %}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Had to figure out a few things, but here is the final call. `{% document_snippets tags__slug='ao-now' %}`